How to have a Local Python Script Send a Dictionary via SSH to a Remote Python Script
In theory
My goal is to have a python script ("s1.py"), which is running locally, initiate a second python script ("s2.py") via ssh on a remote machine. As part of starting s2.py, s1.py would deliver a python dictionary which s2.py would read into memory and subsequently refer to as part of the work it has to do. The dictionary comes from a local file which I want to have remain locally for security reasons, hence the idea of sending it over the wire and into memory (I could, for example, copy the file to the remote machine to a tmpfs space, read it and immediately shred the tmpfs; this would all happen pretty quickly but I still see it as bad practice if I can send the data without having to send the file).
The approach I've been taking is based on the assumption that I can pass this dictionary, via ssh, as a python object from s1.py to s2.py in the form of a command line item, as well as some other command line flags that are required. Something like:
ssh user@remote python3 s2.py python-dict-obj flag1 flag2

S2.py would then read in the object (preferably as a dictionary) in some way or other, e.g.
useful_dict = sys.argv[1], var1_flag1=sys.argv[2], var2_flag2=sys.argv[2]

In practice
As I mentioned, the dictionary comes from a local file which can equally be stored in yaml or json (yaml is preferable). Therefore s1.py can create the dictionary using standard python modules:
with open("local_file", "r", encoding="utf-8") as read_file:
    dict_from_file = json.load(read_file)

with open("local_file", 'r') as stream:
    dict_from_file = yaml.safe_load(stream)

S1.py then attempts, via ssh, to initiate s2.py and send the dictionary, for example using subprocess module:
subprocess.run(['ssh', 'user@remote', 'python3', '/user/scripts/s2.py', 'dict_from_file', 'flag1', 'flag2'])

Problems / Solutions
Does the problem arise because I'm trying to send a dictionary over ssh? Can "dict_from_file" survive as a python object passing through the subprocess module and being sent to the environment/shell of the remote machine? Same when using Paramiko or Fabric?
To date, anything I have tried seems to have s2.py rejecting the data. This would seem to suggest that it may simply not be possible to pass a dictionary in the way I want to. To be fair, I haven't tried anything more adventurous than having s2.py accept inputs at the command line using the sys module so perhaps there is a way to ingest the data in a different way.
Even if it's not possible to transmit an actual dictionary object over ssh, surely the raw data can be sent in json format? A json string (json.dumps?) perhaps although I don't have experience with this? Then, presumbly s2.py can read the string and reconstruct a dictionary?
Or, is my approch just too naive? Do I need to explore sockets/pipes/multiprocesses to achieve what I'm trying to do. On a basic level I'm just trying to perform some simple (I think) data transmission so I'm hoping that there's a brief, elegant way of doing this. Any and all suggestions are welcome.

You can't literally send a dictionary, which is a binary object.  You can certainly convert it to JSON and send the JSON string, or you can use a pickle and send the resulting string to the stdin of the SSH process.

Thank you. Are there particular advantages to pickle vs json? I understand the security concerns about pickle but all the traffic happens within a vpn so I'm not too concerned about that. Otherwise?

I've converted the dictionary to a json object using json.dumps. I then "ssh remote python3 s2.py json_obj". In the remote script, I take the object from the command line "json_dict = sys.argv[1]". I then run "dict1 = json.loads(json_dict)". This returns the error "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)". I've seen this before. It seems like a formatting issue but I'm not quite sure how to fix it.

Did you quote the string?  You'd need to wrap the whole thing with single quotes, in order to make the command line correct.  Otherwise, you'll have to feed it in via stdin.

Sorry to belabor but this is what I'm doing.
S1.py - dict_from_file = get_yaml(pw_file); json_dict_string = dict_to_json(dict_from_file); cmd = shlex.split(f"ssh use@remote python3 script2.py '{json_dict_string}'"); subprocess.run(cmd).
Script2.py has pw_dict = json.loads(sys.argv[1]) to accept the json string.
When I run it all I get the error TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list.

You get that error where?  In the first file or the second?  Instead of shlex.split, perhaps you should create  the list of arguments by hand.  You only have 5 elements.

The error now arises with the second script. The code to take in the string in the second script is "json.loads(sys.argv[1])" and it returns the error from before: "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)". Here's the cmd code, args by hand, with the string double-quoted as you advised: cmd = ['ssh', 'user@remote, 'python3', 's2.py', '"'+json_str+'"']

This works for me.  However, there are some caveats.  This will NOT work if the JSON contains any strings with single quotes.  Fixing that, unfortunately, leads to a maze of twisty passages.
import sys
import json
import subprocess

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    x = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
    print('SUBPROCESS')
    print(sys.argv[1],flush=True)
    print(x)
else:
    s = json.load(open('x.json'))
    cmd = [ 'ssh', 'timr@localhost', 'python', __file__, "'"+json.dumps(s)+"'" ]
    print("MAIN")
    subprocess.run(cmd)

Output:
MAIN
SUBPROCESS
{"id": "123ab", "operation": "foo", "metadata": {"source": "ddb", "destination": "s3"}, "data": "02-02-2024"}
{'id': '123ab', 'operation': 'foo', 'metadata': {'source': 'ddb', 'destination': 's3'}, 'data': '02-02-2024'}

If you DO have more complicated input, you can feed your text in via stdin:
import sys
import json
import subprocess

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print('SUBPROCESS')
    x = sys.stdin.read()
    print('file',x)
    y = json.loads(x)
    print('json',y)
else:
    s = json.load(open('x.json'))
    cmd = [ 'ssh', 'timr@localhost', 'python', __file__, 'x']
    print("MAIN")
    subprocess.run(cmd,input=json.dumps(s).encode())

Output:
SUBPROCESS
file {"id": "123ab", "operation": "foo", "metadata": {"source": "ddb", "destination": "s3"}, "data": "02-02-2024"}
json {'id': '123ab', 'operation': 'foo', 'metadata': {'source': 'ddb', 'destination': 's3'}, 'data': '02-02-2024'}
MAIN


Tim, thank you very much. Just to make sure I get this: this is effectively my script1? The 'if' section performs the accepts the input (prob from a json file) and the 'else' does the sending? What is meant by 'python', file, 'x' ? Do I not need to give an actual location of the file on the remote? What does '--'file'--' mean?

I combined both scripts into one, for ease of demo.  If there's no parameter, it acts as the sender.  If there is a parameter, it acts as the receiver.  __file__ is the name of the file that's running.  Just substitute your own user@server and script name.
